# relationship between readable, visible and read only'

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, security, permissions, field-level-security

In a profile I can see:

```
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>Time_Log__c.Date__c</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

but using the 'Set Field-Level Security' web interface I can only see:  visible  and  'Read Only' options. Please, tell me what means readable? I suspect it means     readable = Read Only  +  Visible

am I right?

Comment: Readable -- means visible. Editable -- means can be edited. If Editable is true, than Readable is true (as a rule). If Editable is false, and Readable is true -- that mean field is read only.

Comment: Also, `Hidden` would indicate both flags are false.

Answer (score 1):

Editable means whether this field is editable or not. In the Profile web interface if you see the "Read Only" as unchecked then the field is editable.

Readable means whether the user who is assigned to the Profile can read this field or not. In the Profile web interface, if you see that the "Visible" option is checked, then you would see this Readable as true in the Profile xml.

For more info, please see this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm (ProfileFieldLevelSecurity section).